# What is the best way to create a list from the rows of a grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, extjs5

In my app there are two drag and drop grid.

To create a list, you drag rows from the first to the second grid.

What is the best way to send this list of rows (second grid) for the server to then be displayed in another grid?

I tried to sync and setDirty (true), but "Ext.data.Model # setDirty" is deprecated.

```
    var grid = this.lookupReference('gridRef');
    var store = grid.getStore();
    store.each(function(record){
        record.setDirty(true);
    });

    store.sync();
```

I tried, unsuccessfully:

```
    var grid = this.lookupReference('gridRef');
    var store = grid.getStore();
    grid.getSelectionModel().selectAll(); 
    var selection = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
    var values = [];

    for(var i=0; i<selection.length; i++) {
        values.push(selection[i].get('order'));
        values.push(selection[i].get('item'));
    }

     var model = Ext.create('app.myModel', values);
     console.log(model) //show just one item
     ????
```

EDITED:

```
    var grid = this.lookupReference('gridRef');
    var store = grid.getStore();        

    var records = store.getRange();

    var create = 'create'; //PHP CRUD » case create

    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'php/crudActionList.php?create',
        method: 'POST',
        params : create,
        jsonData: records,
       // jsonData: Ext.encode(records),
       // jsonData: Ext.JSON.encode(records),
        success: function(conn, response, options, eOpts) {
               console.log('Success!');
        },
        failure: function(conn, response, options, eOpts) {
           console.log('failure')
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send the whole range of records from the store to the server in a single `Ext.Ajax.request`, you could try:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url:'testURL',
    jsonData:store.getRange()
});
```

Or you can have a special field in your record, that contains whether or not the record is in the list. Set the non-persistent boolean field to defaultValue `false`, and `onDrop` set it to true. And voilá, the record should be dirty.

Comment: Thank you Alexander. getRange () works well.
However I am getting the following error: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
I edited my question with my code.

Comment: Sorry, forgot that you have to extract the data from the records. A record contains a link to the store, which contains a link to the record... if that's serialized as a simple tree, it'll be endless. Try `store.getRange().map(function(record) { return record.getData() })`.

Comment: Thanks again Alexander.