# Save whole range of (grid) records in new records list

Tags: javascript, php, extjs, grid, extjs5

I'm trying to send the whole range of (the grid) records from the store to the server in a single ajax request and save all records in another table.

However it seems to lack some detail.

On the client side a *console.log (records)* displays all the objects to be sent.

On the client side a *echo 'console.log ("PHP:'. $ data. '")' exit;* returns  *console.log ("PHP:  ");*

EXTJS 5

```
newList: function (button, e, eOpts) {

    var grid = this.lookupReference('gridRef');
    var store = grid.getStore(),

   // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37663867/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-list-from-the-rows-of-a-grid

    //get whole range of records from the store
    var records = store.getRange().map(function(record) { return record.getData() }); 

    //console.log(records); // OK


    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'php/newList.php?',
        method: 'POST',
        //jsonData: records,
        params:{records:Ext.encode(records)} //EDITED

        success: function(conn, response, options, eOpts) {
               console.log('Success');
        },
        failure: function(conn, response, options, eOpts) {
           console.log('Error')
        }
    });
```

PHP

```
    $records = stripslashes($_POST['records']);
    $data = json_decode($records, true);

    //var_dump($_POST);
    // echo 'console.log("PHP: '.$data.'")', exit;  


    foreach($data as $row) {
        $item[] = $row['item'];
    }


     for($i=0; $i<count($data);$i++){

         $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO tab_list (item) VALUES (?)";
     }

    if($statement = $conexao->prepare($sqlQuery)){
        $statement->bind_param("s", $item[$i]);
        $statement->execute();
        $success= true;
    }else{
        $erro = $conexao->error;
        $success = false;
    }

    $sucess = array("success" => mysqli_errno($conexao) == 0);

    echo json_encode(array(
        "success" => $sucess
    ));

    $statement->close();
    $conexao->close();
```

**EDITED:**

I changed in ajax request `jsonData: records` for 
 `params:{records:Ext.encode(records)}`

With `var_dump($_POST);` on PHP code I get the following response on DevTools

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {  
    ["item"]=>
    string(9) "item five"
    ["id"]=>
    string(22) "MyList.listDataModel-1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["item"]=>
    string(10) "item seven"
    ["id"]=>
    string(22) "MyList.listDataModel-2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    ["item"]=>
    string(9) "item four"
    ["id"]=>
    string(22) "MyList.listDataModel-3"
  }
...
```

However, I am still not able to insert these data in the table and create a new list. The problem is now in the PHP code.

**PHP solution:**

```
  $records = stripslashes($_POST['records']);
  $data = json_decode($records, true);

//var_dump($_POST);
// echo 'console.log("PHP: '.$data.'")', exit;  


foreach($data as $row) {
    $item[] = $row['item'];
}


 for($i=0; $i<count($data);$i++){

     $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO tab_list (item) VALUES (?)";  

     //within for
     if($statement = $conexao->prepare($sqlQuery)){
     $statement->bind_param("s", $item[$i]);
     $statement->execute();
     $success= true;
 }else{
    $erro = $conexao->error;
    $success = false;
    }
}

$sucess = array("success" => mysqli_errno($conexao) == 0);

echo json_encode(array(
    "success" => $sucess
));

$statement->close();
$conexao->close();
```

Comment: Is `$item` initialized prior to that `foreach` loop? Looks like you intended the `if($statement = $conexao->prepare(...` line to be within the `for` (or possibly the `foreach`) loop.

Comment: Thanks reformed. What surprises me, first of all, it is the console.log not display any data. Supposedly should display console.log ("PHP: Array"); corresponding to objects sent from the client side with the ajax request.

Comment: Instead of printing `console.log`, try `var_dump($_POST)` to see what data is actually being sent to newList.php. Examine the response in the **Network** tab of the console log.

Comment: With var_dum($_POST) returns array(0) { } {"success":{"success":false}}.

Comment: Then there's no data being sent to newList.php. `$records` and `$data` will be empty.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I'm making some testing to try to identify what is wrong.

Comment: I edited my post. Now data is being sent to server side

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($data);`?

Comment: I edited my question with de output and the solution. I solved with the sugestion of your frst comment. Thanks again reformed.

Comment: reformed, If you want to convert your first comment to reply, I mark as answered.
Otherwise, as my question has too many characters, I will delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `$item` initialized prior to that foreach loop? Looks like you intended the `if($statement = $conexao->prepare(...` line to be within the `for` (or possibly the `foreach`) loop.

After editing your question, consider using a *single* `INSERT` statement as an alternative to your solution:

```
$total = count($item);
$sqlQuery = 'INSERT INTO tab_list (item) VALUES ' . rtrim(str_repeat('(?),', $total), ',');
$statement = $conexao->prepare($sqlQuery);

if ($statement)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++)
    {
        $statement->bind_param('s', $item[$i]);
    }

    $statement->execute();
    $success = true;
}
else
{
    $erro = $conexao->error;
    $success = false;
}
```

Comment: No problem. Happy coding